# Why does Symfony 3.4 / Doctrine 2.6 removes the UNIQUE constraint on my ID field?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. Beside Symfony I updated some other components as well, like Doctrine:

```
                                  Symfony 2.8       Symfony 3.4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
symfony/symfony                   v2.8.49           v3.4.21
doctrine/annotations                       v1.6.0           
doctrine/cache                             v1.8.0         
doctrine/collections                       v1.5.0
doctrine/common                   v2.8.1            v2.10.0
doctrine/dbal                     v2.6.3            v2.9.2
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                   1.10.0
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle             1.3.5
doctrine/event-manager                              v1.0.0
doctrine/inflector                         v1.3.0
doctrine/instantiator                      1.1.0
doctrine/lexer                             v1.0.1
doctrine/orm                      v2.5.14           v2.6.3 
doctrine/persistence                                v1.1.0
doctrine/reflection                                 v1.0.0
```

On some entities I use a `GUID` as primary key:

```
class SomeEntity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="guid", type="guid", unique=true)
     */
    protected $guid;

    ...
 }
```

The DB created with the SF 2.8 project uses both an `PRIMARY` and an `UNIQUE` constraint on these fields. However when running a DB Update with SF 3.4 doctrine wants to remove the `UNIQUE` constraints:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

The following SQL statements will be executed:

 DROP INDEX UNIQ_D3D1CD162B6FCFB2 ON some_enitiy;
```

**Is this correct?**

Since the fields are still defined as `PRIMARY` they should be unique anyway and I assume that it would be save to remove the `UNIQUE` property. **But is it save to do this?**

Is the updated Doctrine version smarter and minifies the redundant definition of `PRIMARY` and `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY` only, or is there some other reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.

You do not need a UNIQUE on a PRIMARY field .

Although it is not an error to use UNIQUE and PRIMARY both, the UNIQUE is redundant (makes your database slower, consumes more disk space) and can be removed safely and should be removed.